# Create image from RAID images

Tags: raid, data-recovery, disk-image

I have 3 raw images of what was once a 3 disk RAID5 setup. The hardware has been lost and the configuration is unknown.

Does anyone know of some software that can automatically detect the raid configuration and write a single image out?

Answer (score 2):

What kind of controller card were you using?  Many of them save the array's configuration to the disk, and a replacement card can import that data.